# Locking down a REST API to one app. How?

Tags: api, rest, mobile

I have a small one page browser based app which consumes a REST API. Users are authenticated via a shortish lived token based system.

I'm likely going to expand this to also include mobile apps (either native or hybrid) which will also consume the same API.

I do have one concern though - how can I 'lock' my API so that only my apps can consume it?

In other words, how can I stop someone else building an app that uses my API?

Comment: You mean other than: not documenting it, having some kind of preshared secret to make calls, etc.? (And of course, most "locks" can be "picked" with enough time and effort)

Comment: As an aside, also consider that some of the more popular websites around nowadays have got there in part *because they had an open API* (Twitter is the textbook example, but also consider Facebook, Instagram, Flickr, etc.)

Comment: Yes, a preshared secret could easily be grabbed from the source code. It's not a massive issue - just wondered if it was possible. Thx.

Comment: Also, agreed - an open API is often a good thing. :o)

Comment: If they've got your source, the gate is locked open, and the horse already bolted :) You could consider something *like* OAuth, with a magic method to handle the log-on without the full OAuth authorisation - you could restrict that method to your "known good" client API keys, or similar.

Comment: Yes, the source will be freely available I guess, as it's a pure js app that's fully portable. I think my main concern was someone building another app on top of my API... although in retrospect that may not be too bad a thing. The data is free for consumers to access, but there's a paywall to get it into the app (and this happens outside of the consumer API) so more consumers, regardless of how they access the data, is definitely a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of authentication, and if you're going to do authentication you'll need to make your REST API use HTTPS. Basic auth usually fits the bill nicely. Your apps will have credentials, but your human users will not. This will also allow you to give credentials to a customer, or somebody who wishes to use your API if you would like.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I have a slightly differently-purposed API. It's the human users who have the credentials.

Comment: Well authentication is the best way to lock it down. Different credentials can have different roles (humans vs. applications). That "preshared secret" you guys were discussing before is a very simplistic form of authentication. You'll still need HTTPS otherwise that secret won't be secret for long.

Comment: Of course, HTTPS goes without saying. :o) No auth credentials (usernames/passwords etc) are stored on client devices either. Requests to secure API endpoints are authenticated with a token that has an expiry date.

Comment: I guess what I meant was, does a native app have a unique id (an app store id, for example) that can be passed with each request... but then that's not hard to get hold of either!

Comment: I guess I'm confused. The native app can have its set of credentials. These should be hidden from the user of the app. Perhaps you encrypt them and place them in a file that the application can access. Your application would decrypt the credentials and use them to authenticate with your REST API over HTTPS. This will ensure that nobody is able to discover your app's credentials. Nobody except your applications will be able to use the REST API because nobody except your applications have credentials.

Comment: You could even implement an authentication scheme where a unique device-specific id is used (perhaps this is what you're referring to). This would allow you to refuse access to a specific device if they are using your API maliciously (for example performing a denial of service attack on your API).